# Why are opencv's Mat::rows and Mat::cols signed instead of unsigned?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm compiling a program with gcc's `-Wall` flag. I do a comparison (with an unsigned int) on `Mat::cols` and `Mat::rows` at some point and get a warning about comparing signed and unsigned ints. Although it's not a big deal to cast this away, I'm curious as to what the rationale behind a `Mat` that has a negative size is.

Logically, a matrix can't be any emptier than an empty matrix (with 0 rows and 0 cols), so what would a matrix with -1 rows or -1 cols mean?

[There doesn't seem to be much performance difference between computations on signed and unsigned ints either.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712315/performance-of-unsigned-vs-signed-integers)

Comment: I think it is simply a design flaw. A lot of people, including writers of many well-known and large libraries, make not so good use of integer types. Using `int` for all kinds of integers is a common mistake.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, my bad. I thought about values in Mat. Deleting my post.

Comment: i hate it too that .rows and .cols are signed... just got used to loop over unsigned types for std::vector...

Comment: I think what vlad said about int loop counters could be a reason. I personally always use size_t as loop counter type. Requires more typing, but is the correct type for sizes and indices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think because mostly `int i` is used as loop counter. with uint as cols and rows many warnings will appear. Also bulding differences of dimensions would be a bit more error prone.

beside that. in my opinions OpenCv is not a good example of good design at all.
there are dozens of examples of bad class design. Also the design of the generated documentation is terrible (all overloads of a function and its parameters are mixed together for example).

But it is a very comprehensive and good image processing library. and that excuses a lot :)