# When to use unsigned values over signed ones (how do)?

Tags: c++

When is it appropriate to use an unsigned variable over a signed one? What about in a for loop?

I hear a lot of opinions about this and I wanted to see if there was anything resembling a consensus.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < someThing.length(); i++) {  
    SomeThing var = someThing.at(i);  
    // You get the idea.   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712315/performance-of-unsigned-vs-signed-integers

Answer (score 2):

In your specific case, you should use the type which does *not* generate an **implicit type conversion** in this expression:

```
i < someThing.length();
```

i.e. you should use the exact type of `someThing.length()`. Look at its signature and use its return type for your local variable `i`.

Don't think of loop variables as something special. If you're working with `length`, use the type of `length`. Try to be as consistent as possible within your project, avoiding unnecessary type conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a signed variable when the value can be negative.

A length should always be positive and is because of this usually represented with an `unsigned` type. It is the consensus as far as I can see in the standard library and other big libraries (often named `size_t` for example ).

It is better to use `unsigned int` for i because in case the length is big you won't have overflow problems but usually it makes no difference.

Many compilers will also give you a warning if you compare a `int` (signed) with and `unsigned int` because of this issue.

Comment: For array indexes or anything bound by memory space, use `size_t`, rather than `unsigned int`, though this does result in a potential memory inefficiency on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: I would say that people usually know if the maximum index value will be small (maybe a couple thousands) or huge. Cases that require allocating a 64-bit index are pretty rare and unless you have unlimited memory you should pretty much know when this happens. I was only focusing on signed versus unsigned and the size for the array indexes is very rarely a problem.

Comment: Assuming word-alignment, the effective memory space used by `uint32_t` would be the same as `size_t` on x64.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should use a signed type when negative numbers are involved - the interesting question is whether it's still good to do so when the value is known to be non-negative but clearly doesn't need the extra range the equivalent unsigned type offers.

There is no concensus.  Some considerations:

- the real-world import of some variables is inherently signed (e.g. a person's age), unsigned variables can encode/communicate that to a programmer reading the source code
- I'm not aware of any compiler that warns if you pass unsigned types into functions expecting signed or vice versa; claims that the choice of type can enforce correctness are dubious
- many compilers do warn if signed and unsigned types are compared
- some specific variables/types in libraries are either signed or unsigned, and it may make sense to use the same types for variables interacting with them, ensuring the representable range is the same
- code like `while (n-- >= 0)` and `abs(a - b)` may not do what's wanted given unsigned types, which is one reason to have a general preference for signed types